# Assets vs drawable hdpi for android game?

Tags: android

I was working on an android game and read that the best practice is to use the assets folder.  After loading all my files from there i got some problems later that said vm budget has been exceeded.  I am told that the assets is the best because android does not modify the contents like it does with the drawable folders.  If i use drawable hdpi on my tablet(I want to eventually make a tablet game), everything runs fine and the textures do not have to be recycled.  I know this has to be a bad practice, so how can i use assets folder with out having the vm budget problem if i am using a tile map which works with loading images from drawable hdpi.  Or is this fine?

In short, using drawable hdpi to load files has worked fine but assets has not even though i am told that assets is better to work with for games.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with creating a folder named drawable (without hdpi/ldpi/mdpi) in res